# editing and reordering tuples in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [(1, "text"), (2, "more"), (5, "more"), (10, "more")]
```

The tuples have the structure `(int, string)` and start from 1 and the max value is 10. I would like to edit and reorder them to the following:

```
lst2 = [(1, "text"), (2, "more"), (3, ""), (4, ""), (5, "more"), (6, ""), (7, ""), (8, ""),
       (9, ""), (10, "more")]
```

As you can see I want to create a new list that is consecutively numbered up to 10. All int's from the tuples in the first list `lst` that doesn't occur in the range of 1 to 10 will produce an empty string in the new list `lst2`.

I came up with this code:

```
lst2 = []
for tupl in lst:
  for k in range(1,11):
    if tupl[0] == k:
      lst2.append((k, tupl[1]))
    else:
      lst2.append((k, ""))
print lst2
```

however the result is weird:

```
[(1, 'text'), (2, ''), (3, ''), (4, ''), (5, ''), (6, ''), (7, ''), (8, ''), (9, ''),
(10, ''), (1, ''), (2, 'more'), (3, ''), (4, ''), (5, ''), (6, ''), (7, ''), (8, ''),
(9, ''), (10, ''), (1, ''), (2, ''), (3, ''), (4, ''), (5, 'more'), (6, ''), (7, ''),
(8, ''), (9, ''), (10, ''), (1, ''), (2, ''), (3, ''), (4, ''), (5, ''), (6, ''), (7, ''),
(8, ''), (9, ''), (10, 'more')]
```

Can anyone please help me or tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = [(1, "text"), (2, "more"), (5, "more"), (10, "more")]
d = dict(lst)
lst2 = [(i, d.get(i, "")) for i in range(1, 11)]
```

**EDIT**

Or, using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
lst = [(1, "text"), (2, "more"), (5, "more"), (10, "more")]
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(str, lst)
lst2 = [(i, d[i]) for i in range(1, 11)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for is excessive here.
Instead of for k in range(1,11): you should use if k>=1 and k<=10:

Answer (score 1):

There are already better answers, but just to show you how your loop could be modified to yield the desired result:

```
for k in range(1,11):
  exists=False
  for tupl in lst:
    if tupl[0] == k:
      lst2.append((k, tupl[1]))
      exists = True
      break
  if not exists:
    lst2.append((k, ""))
print lst2
```